# lvalue required as left operand of assignment error in c++

Tags: c++, vector

All of my fellas, i have a problem with my code. I try to use macro and vector in my code. But, there is an error in my code, exactly in the macro code. I dont know what is the error.
This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

#define LOOP(a,b) for((int)(a) = 0; (a) < (int)(b); (a)++)

int main(){

    vector<string> sentence;
    sentence.reserve(10);

    int i=0, c = sentence.size();

    sentence.push_back("Hello,");
    sentence.push_back("how");
    sentence.push_back("are");
    sentence.push_back("you");
    sentence.push_back("?");

    LOOP(i,c){
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope some of you can help me to solve this problem.
Regards.

Comment: What is your purpose for that `(int)` in front of `(int)(a)=0;` ??

Comment: @MooingDuck for whatever reason, he wants to use the `i` in `main()` as the macro parameter to `a`. Otherwise I see no reason for the `a` macro parameter whatsoever. Just to name the for-loop index seems as odd as the macro itself

Comment: Rather than using a macro, make some kind of range or use `boost::irange`. `for (auto i : range(c)) {std::cout << i;}`. It's easier when you don't need indices: `for (const auto &word : sentence) {std::cout << word;}`

Answer (score 4):

It is a bad idea to use such kind of macros in C++. The problem is that expression

```
( int )( a )
```

is rvalue (some temporary object) and you may not assign a value to it like

```
( int )( a ) = 0;
```

Either remove entirely the casting or at least use casting like `( int & )`.

Also when you reserve a memory for a vector using a value that is greater than the current size of the vector then the size will not be changed. So
in this code snippet

```
vector<string> sentence;
sentence.reserve(10);

int i=0, c = sentence.size();
```

c will be equal to 0.

You should assign c after calling push_back.

```
int i=0;

sentence.push_back("Hello,");
sentence.push_back("how");
sentence.push_back("are");
sentence.push_back("you");
sentence.push_back("?");

int c = sentence.size();
```

Also I do not see any relation between the vector and the loop. In my opinion this loop

```
LOOP(i,c){
        cout << i << endl;
```

does not make sense. Maybe you mean to output elements of the vector do you?

In this case the loop could look like

```
for ( const auto &s : sentence ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

First: That should not be a macro. People are familiar enough with loop semantics that trying to macro it is... odd. If it really bothers you and your compiler supports C++11 range-based for loops you can do `for ( auto i: sentence )`

Second: `sentence.size()` is 0 when it is referenced, so c will be 0 and is never updated. Your loop would never run.

Answer (score 0):

sentence.size() will return 0 as you have not pushed any items into it yet, so your loop will never run.

Why are you using a macro to do a for loop anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

#define LOOP(a,b) for(a = 0; a < b; a++)

int main(){

        vector<string> sentence;
        sentence.reserve(10);

        sentence.push_back("Hello,");
        sentence.push_back("how");
        sentence.push_back("are");
        sentence.push_back("you");
        sentence.push_back("?");

        int i=0, c = sentence.size();

        LOOP(i,c){
            cout << i << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

1.) You filled your vector AFTER you asked for the size to do your loop, so c is 0.

2.) You macro was wrong

Comment: Don't fix the macro-loop code, you're enabling him!  :)